# How to check if there is a string equal to your variable in a csv file line

Tags: python, csv

I have a variable (aTerm) which contains an 8 digit random number which im using to uniquely identify each individual line of a csv file.

Here is the code I wrote to remove the line which has the corresponding number:

```
def rebuildFile(aTerm, aFile):
    with open(aFile, 'r') as oldFile, open('static\\new.csv', 'w') as newFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            if not aTerm in line:
                newFile.write(line)
return
```

The only trouble is that it doesn't work at all unless I type out the 8 digit number as a string in the if statement. So this works perfectly:

```
def rebuildFile(aTerm, aFile):
    with open(aFile, 'r') as oldFile, open('static\\new.csv', 'w') as newFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            if not "45893243" in line:
                newFile.write(line)
return
```

I don't understand and would greatly appreciate the help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `aTerm` to `str` in order to compare it to a `str`:

```
def rebuildFile(aTerm, aFile):
    sTerm = str(aTerm)
    with open(aFile, 'r') as oldFile, open('static\\new.csv', 'w') as newFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            if not sTerm in line:
                newFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Yeah that did it, I wrote it off because I tried casting it as a string before it went into the function and also in the if statement line and neither worked, but in this exact way it worked first time. Many thanks :)

Comment: Hold on actually it didn't work, please excuse me it's nearly 5am casting it to a string doesn't help and I believe it already is a string anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason the innerHTML I had passed from my webpage to flask had a tonne of spaces around it so I had to strip it. This question has been answered by Reblochon Masque.